# How to use systemd-inhibit without sudo?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, process, systemd

I have an SBC (pine64) running Ubuntu 16_04 and I have a long process to do (build tensorflow). I'm using the `nohup` command to detach the process from my SSH session but two days consecutively my board rebooted at midnight. I saw that I can inhibit reboot, sleep and shutdown with `systemd-inhibit`.

Is there a way to use this command without sudo? Bazel build doesn't recognize my `%JAVA_HOME` when launched with `sudo`...

This is the command I'm trying to run:

```
systemd-inhibit --why="Compiling TF" nohup bazel build -c opt --copt="-funsafe-math-optimiza
tions" --copt="-ftree-vectorize" --copt="-fomit-frame-pointer" --verbose_failures tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_pa
ckage &
```

which gives me:

```
Failed to inhibit: Access denied
```

Any advice?

Comment: Maybe you can run ```systemd-inhibit sleep 100000``` in parallel with your build?

Comment: @Scott, I launched sudo `sudo systemd-inhibit sleep 518400` to be safe for 6 days and then run my build command without the systemd-inhibit.
I still had to use sudo, is it normal?

Comment: It seems reasonable that you would need to use `sudo` on a command that modifies the behavior of the system.

Comment: Yes ok seems reasonable. Also I used `sudo nohup systemd-inhibit sleep 518400` to detach the process from my SSH session. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: The real question is why your board reboots at night? Have you configured it to reboot at specific times?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `systemd-inhibit --what=idle` as a normal user to prevent the machine from suspending due to system idleness. Other locks require elevated privileges.

Answer (score 0):

I had tested `systemd-inhibit --what=idle` and `systemd-inhibit --what=sleep` commands, both of them can using in normal user.

BTW, if you use `elogind-inhibit` all of the `--what=` arguments are working (if you set one).