# Allow non-privileged user to do systemd-inhibit

Tags: systemd, policykit

I have script running from non-privileged user. It is important, so systemd-inhibit is a good idea. But I get error when trying to inhibit from that user

```
systemd-inhibit sleep 10
Failed to inhibit: Access denied
```

This user not so trusted to put him in "wheel" group. How can I grant permission to that user to run systemd-inhibit? (PolicyKit?)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to inhibit suspension, you can use `systemd-inhibit --what=idle` as a normal user to prevent the machine from suspending due to system idleness. Other locks require elevated privileges (credits to [Aeyoun](https://superuser.com/users/81165/aeyoun)'s [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1621311)).